# Testing async function in service angular :async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine

Tags: javascript, angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

Here is the method in the service that I want to test

```
public loadConfigurations():Promise <any> {
      return this.http.get(environment.BASE_URL).toPromise()
}
```

In the  test.spec.ts

```
it('Should be return the enviroment configs from rest api',done =>{

          service.loadConfigurations().then((data)=>{
            console.log('data',data)
            expect(data).toBe('test')
            done();
          }).catch((err)=>{
            console.log(err);
          })

  })
```

I am getting the

> Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout
>   specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.

When I run the tests without the above case, there is no timeout error so i belive something messed-up in my service

**karma config**

```
    captureTimeout: 210000,
    browserDisconnectTolerance: 3,
    browserDisconnectTimeout: 210000,
    browserNoActivityTimeout: 210000,
```

Comment: Don't wrap an existing promise in a new promise (it doesn't solve your issue but it needs to be pointed out). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it

Comment: Thanks, @Lennholm i've updated with proper with proper pattern

Comment: I can't see anything obviously wrong in your code. Are you getting any other error? I'm thinking the timeout might simply be secondary, a consequence of never reaching the `done()` call because the test fails before that point.

Comment: No errors one thing i have noticed is the code in the `then` is not reachable